# Snakes with multiple heads

Tags: naga

There are several mentions about nagas in Hinduism. Consider the following excerpt from Mahabharata

> "O Brahmana, thus I have recited the names of the principal snakes
> known widely for their achievements--I have not been able to name all,
> the number being countless. The sons of these snakes, the sons of
> those sons, that were burnt having fallen into the fire, I am unable
> to mention. They are so many! **Some of three heads, some of seven,
> others of ten**, of poison like unto the fire at the end of the yuga and
> terrible in form,--they were burnt by thousands!
>
> [[22, Section 57, Astika Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01058.htm)

The passage mentions about nagas with three heads, seven heads and ten heads.

Are there any other mentions in Hindu scriptures saying about snakes with multiple heads other than three, seven and ten?

Comment: Bhagavad Gita mentions - nagaanam sesha.

Comment: @ram How many heads do nagaanam sesha has?

Comment: haha.. not 'naganaam sesha' - it's among nagas, i am sesha. among sarpa, i am vasuki. sarpa = 1 head, naga =  multiple heads. doesn't specify exact number.

Comment: AdiShesha has 1000 hoods. Btw scripture tag is when you ask directly *about* scriptures whereas this question is asking about a reference of multiple heads of nagas. So Naga tag is enough. :) We will quote or write answers based on Hindu scriptures only right? For that scripture tag is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

**Are there any other mentions in Hindu scriptures saying about snakes with multiple heads other than three, seven and ten?**

Yes, such mentions are in Bhagavata Purana or Śrīmad Bhāgavata (SB).

[SB 5.25](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/25/2) describes Lord Ananta Deva as

> sahasra-śirasaḥ — who has thousands of hoods

Also, as described in [Difference between Naaga and Sarpa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31784/difference-between-naaga-and-sarpa/31794#31794) post, **SB 5.24** mentions

> they have many, many hoods — some snakes **five** hoods, some seven, some ten, others a **hundred** and others a **thousand**.